# Linking GLFW in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, linker-errors, glfw

I recently tried to understand how to link GLFW, GLEW, glm and Soil2 in Visual Studio Code. I am using mingw 32 bit on a USB key as I prefer being able to program whenever I got a free hour in Highschool and all computers (at school and at home) have Windows installed. Here are my JSON files:

tasks.json (with libwinmm.a):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "build",

        "command": "E:/Compiler/mingw32/bin/g++.exe",

        "args": [
          "-g",
          "-o",
          "${workspaceFolder}/opengl.exe",

          /* .cpp Files */
          "${workspaceFolder}/code/main.cpp",

          /* Include paths */
          "-IE:/Compiler/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++",
          "-I${workspaceFolder}/external/GLEW/include",
          "-I${workspaceFolder}/external/GLFW/include",
          "-I${workspaceFolder}/external/glm/..",
          "-I${workspaceFolder}/external/Soil2/Include",
          "-I${workspaceFolder}",
          "-I${workspaceFolder}/code",

          /* Library paths */
          "-LE:/Compiler/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib",
          "-L${workspaceFolder}/external/GLEW/lib",
          "-L${workspaceFolder}/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015",
          "-L${workspaceFolder}/external/Soil2/lib",

          /* Libraries */
          "-lmingw32",
          "-lwinmm",
          "-lgdi32",
          "-lopengl32",
          "-lshell32",
          "-luser32",
          "-lglew32",
          "-lglfw3",
          "-lsoil2"
        ],

        "options": {
          "cwd": "E:/Compiler/mingw32/bin"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

launch.json:

```
 {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "build",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/opengl.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "E:/Compiler/mingw32/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "version": 4,
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "E:/Compiler/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++",
                "${workspaceFolder}/external/GLEW/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/external/GLFW/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/external/glm/..",
                "${workspaceFolder}/external/Soil2/Include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/code/.."
            ],
            "defines": [
                "GLEW_STATIC",
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "E:/Compiler/mingw32/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is the example code from GLFW documentation I put in code/main.cpp (with glew code):

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#endif // _WIN32

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(!glewInit())
      return -1;

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling, this program return this error log:

```
> Executing task: E:/Compiler/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -g -o E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/opengl.exe 
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/code/main.cpp -IE:/Compiler/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64- 
mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++ -IE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLEW/include - 
IE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/include -IE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/glm/.. - 
IE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/Soil2/Include -IE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl - 
IE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/code -LE:/Compiler/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib - 
LE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLEW/lib -LE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015 -LE:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/Soil2/lib -lmingw32 -winmm -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lshell32 - 
luser32 -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lsoil2 <

Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
C:\Users\willy\AppData\Local\Temp\ccRDHcUY.o: In function `main':
E:/Programmes/Projets/Opengl/code/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x46): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x131): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x23e): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x2a8): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/window.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x2d5): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x35): undefined reference to `_ultod3'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x46): undefined reference to `_ultod3'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x46): undefined reference to `_ultod3'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/input.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x51): undefined reference to `_dtoul3'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x6): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x5a): undefined reference to `_imp____stdio_common_vsprintf'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/init.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0xa6): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0xc4): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0xea): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x187): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x37e): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/context.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x3b8): more undefined references to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4' follow
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x14): undefined reference to 
`_dtoui3'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x7e): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xf1): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x123): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x153): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x8b): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xa2): undefined reference to 
`_imp__CreateDIBSection@24'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xd6): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xef): undefined reference to 
`_imp__CreateBitmap@20'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x112): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DeleteObject@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x1b7): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DeleteObject@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x1f7): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x116): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x184): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x1f5): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x2a): undefined reference to @ 
__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_window.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x56): more undefined references 
to `@__security_check_cookie@4' follow
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x34): undefined reference to 
`_imp__CreateDCW@16'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x42): undefined reference to 
`_imp__GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x49): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DeleteDC@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x97): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x7e): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x26d): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x97): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x238): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x47): more undefined references 
to `@__security_check_cookie@4' follow
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x92): undefined reference to 
`_imp__CreateDCW@16'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xa0): undefined reference to 
`_imp__SetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xa7): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DeleteDC@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xb7): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xef): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x115): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x58): undefined reference to 
`_imp__CreateDCW@16'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x5e): undefined reference to 
`_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_monitor.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x7e): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DeleteDC@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xb0): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x8b): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xb2): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x30c): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x232): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x71): more undefined 
references to `@__security_check_cookie@4' follow
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x28a): undefined reference to 
`_libm_sse2_sqrt_precise'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x309): undefined reference to 
`_libm_sse2_sqrt_precise'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x41e): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x47): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x8b): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_joystick.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x190): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_init.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x68): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/win32_init.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xba): more undefined references to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4' follow
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0xb1): undefined reference to `_libm_sse2_pow_precise'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x117): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib-vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/monitor.c.obj): 
(.text$mn+0x14a): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x62): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xb2): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x106): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/egl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x14e): more undefined references 
to `@__security_check_cookie@4' follow
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xb5): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xde): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xf7): undefined reference to 
`_imp__SetPixelFormat@12'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x120): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x425): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x85): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x33d): undefined reference to 
`_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x418): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x44a): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x61): undefined reference to 
`_imp__ChoosePixelFormat@8'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x69): undefined reference to 
`_imp__SetPixelFormat@12'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x8c): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xbc): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xf2): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x1fc): undefined reference to 
`@__security_check_cookie@4'
E:\Programmes\Projets\Opengl/external/GLFW/lib- 
vc2015/glfw3.lib(CMakeFiles/glfw.dir/wgl_context.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x48): undefined reference to 
`_imp__SwapBuffers@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

So neither GLEW or GLFW work, meaning I can only use them with VS Community, which is slower and has no portable mode

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you don't have the **.dll** file in the working dir of the project. Try moving the **GLFW3.dll** file to the compile/run location.

If that does not work then try adding `#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")` and sometimes windows will need a lib like `winmm.lib` so do the same thing there too

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#endif // _WIN32
```

Make sure you also have a opengl lib too like **glew** or **opengl32**

you can find glew here:
[HERE](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)

Note: There is better ways of doing this, this is just my way of importing libs into VS/VScode

Comment: I tried to put the dll file in the compile/run location and it didn't work so I linked libwinmm.a in tasks.json or the way you did it and it didn't work. I tried adding `#include <GL/glew.h>` and                                                                                           `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);                        
 if (!glewInit())
         return -1;` and GLEW linking doesn't cause any problem

Comment: Actually no, this produces another line of error: `C:\Users\willy\AppData\Local\Temp\ccWWdHR4.o: In function `main':
E:/Programmes/Projets/Opengl/code/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0' ` it should mean that glew isn't linked however, I can't find why because I downloaded precompiled glew libraries for my specific compiler.

Comment: are you running it in 64 or 32 bit mode? My 64bit mode does not work for me/

Comment: I don't know, how can I know that ? @Main menu

Answer (score -1):

You should try putting your mingw libs and bin folder in the environment variables. It worked for me.

**Edit:** Also include windows.h before including glew